# Add predefined text to textfile via button click

Tags: php, database, append, text-files

I have a stupidly simple question — it's so simple, I can't find an answer for it :)

I'm absolutely new to PHP (basically started today) and I want to do the following:

Whenever someone clicks a button on a webpage, a character (the letter 'a') is to be added / appended to a textfile or a table in a database. Simultaneosly, I want the (updated) content of this textfile / database to be displayed on the same page.

Ideally, I would also like to store the location, time and date of the person who clicked the button.

Any help? I'd be so gracious.

edit:
here's some code i found for increasing a counter, stored in a textfile, but this seems more complex than what i want to do:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+'); // use 'r+' instead
flock($f, LOCK_EX); // avoid race conditions with concurrent requests
$total = (int) fread($f, max(1, filesize('counter.txt'))); // arg can't be 0
/*if someone has clicked submit*/
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   rewind($f); // move pointer to start of file so we overwrite instead of append
   fwrite($f, ++$total);
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: I don't like key loggers on web sites. Do you?

Comment: i'm sorry — i'm eager to do my best, but i simply have no clue. i searched online for quite a while and i actually only found something that appears more complex to me — a counter than increases as a button is clicked (see above)

Comment: So you have a session with user data, probably userid and name, after they have logged in. Then you want to track when this person clicks certain buttons correct? Then you want to show them how many times they have clicked said button?

Comment: i honestly dont even know if i have a session :) there is no login neccessary. simple page, 1 button. button is clicked -> letter a is displayed. button is clicked again -> another letter a is displayed (aa). and if a new visitor comes to the page, the letters of the previous one are still stored and he can simply add another a.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for this simple task.

```
file_put_contents('counter.txt', 'a', FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

But if you'd like to store informations about your visitors, database is your good friend. 
Start with some [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20tutorial).

Comment: thanks so much.. i've tried the following and of course it doesn't work :/ 
`<?php
$file = fopen('smile.txt', 'r+');
$smiles = "a";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
file_put_contents($file, $smiles, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
fclose($file);
?>`

Comment: file_put_contents() usage is simpler than you think :-). Look at the documentation, the first parameter is the filename and not a resource. Try to use it as in example I have given you in my answer. So try: `<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { file_put_contents('smile.txt', 'a', FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to think of the use of PHP and HTML in terms of server and client process.

```
       HTML                       PHP
        |                          |
     web page                      |
        |                          |
user    |                          |
clicks  |--- request to server --->|
        |                          |file or DB update
        |<--- returns OK - data ---|
        |                          |
        |                          |
```

To send a request to the PHP server, you would use a form, which would be submitted often, and the page reloaded; alternatively, rely on AJAX to control when to send data to the server and handle the updates without reloading the whole page.

Comment: yes, that was my impression. Try and make your question more specific - or ask a new question - once you have more of a plan.